# Apigility returning error even after successfull action

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, zend-framework2

I am building a REST API using Apigility with Zend Framework 2.
In this API, I have a code-connected REST service and I am encountering a strange behaviour when I try to delete an entity.
I use the delete method of my TableGateway object to delete the data passed into the delete method of the "Resource" file:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    //GetTable returns a TableGateway instance
    $this->getTable('order')->delete(array('id' => $id));
    return array("status" => "deleted", "id" => $id);
}
```

I tested this function by using the Postman REST client and got back the response:

```
{
    "type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
    "title":"Unprocessable Entity",
    "status":422,
    "detail":"Unable to delete entity."
}
```

However, when I checked the mysql database, the entity in question was deleted properly.
There were no signs of an error occuring.

What could the cause of such an error being returned be?

Update:
The code reaches the lines after the TableGateway delete function call.
That means the response is probably built after the function is called and the return value I return is ignored.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If modify your delete logic to 'return true' then the API response should render a HTTP 204 as expected.

```
...
class ItemResource extends AbstractResourceListener
{
    ...
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $service = $this->serviceManager->get('...\ItemService');
        $service->deleteItem($id);
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi @camsf i would like to return custom json but i can't able to return is it possible like return new \ZF\ApiProblem\ApiProblemResponse(new \ZF\ApiProblem\ApiProblem(455, 'Member has been deleted'));

Comment: please help me i am unable to return custom json

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a couple years old, but I just ran into this issue myself.  While I don't have a solution, I do believe I've isolated the actual problem, and it is not with your response object. By using breakpoints, I am able to watch the delete event being triggered twice by ZF2 for each API DELETE call.

The first time through, everything works, and you delete your data, but then it all gets called again, resulting in an 'unable to delete this entity' because the entity is no longer there.

Answer (score -1):

You're error is not in the execution of the deletion.. but in the malformed response you're passing back.

After the delete you need to think of how to confirm this properly in a well-formed (likely JSON based) response object.

Comment: But Apigility already converts every returned array or object into a JSON based response object.

Comment: if it cannot read what you're giving it.. you're going to get an unprocessable entity error.  Believe me, I've gotten them too.. it was because what I was returning from a Resource class didn't match the Entity Class I'd specified in the config.

Comment: I have returned countless entities that didn't match the configured entity class and it worked without problems.
Anyway, if I return true or false from the delete-Function, it works. I didn't really need the response object anways.